# Expo Magic Link and Deep Linking

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

```
  const expoLink = Linking.makeUrl();
  const actionCodeURL =
    " what to write here" + `?redirectUrl=${encodeURIComponent(expoLink)}`;
    
  //sending signInLinkToEmail
  const handlePress = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, {
        url: actionCodeURL, // what should be its value so that on clicking this will redirect them to app.
        handleCodeInApp: true,
      })
      .then(()=>{});
  };
```

I am trying to do authentication in my expo app using a firebase. I want to implement **sendSignInLinkToEmail** so that the user receives a link in his/her email. When the user clicks on the link, he/she should get redirected to the app.

I am stuck at the URL section of the second parameter of **sendSignInLinkToEmail** function.

Answer (score -1):

For the use you want, you just have to give the android and ios parameters. These are the project Ids of your android and ios app in the firebase console.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#send_an_authentication_link_to_the_users_email_address

Comment: How can I get the ios and Andriod bundle Ids in Expo?

Comment: I want this to be done without ejecting the expo app.